# Asking for password when pushing updates to GitHub

Tags: github

I initialized a new repository, and pushed my code to GitHub.

After that, I updated my `README` file and tried to push on GitHub again, but when I did that, it asks me for password, and it didn't asked me for password when I pushed my code to GitHub for first time.
[image]

I also tried entering my GitHub account password, it fails.
I also tried use the key which I generated as a password, but still no luck.

Can anyone please guide me how to solve this problem?

This is the error which I am getting after entering the password:

[image]

Comment: Ensure your keys are setup correctly (and used). Github does not accept passwords so the password prompt should be for the *keys*, and that should be a different password than github. Then ensure the public keys are registered on github. I’m not sure “what happened” between the two attempts. — https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: @user2864740 Which keys ? I am only having the password and the token. that's it. Thanks for document, I will check it out

Comment: See link above. Also see the links in said page about checking for existing keys and associating keys with a github account.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks a lot for your help. I created SSH key, after entering passphrase I got a message prompt informing that SSH key was created and saved in a directory. So my question is, while authentication what do I have to enter, the **passphrase** or the **SHA256** which it generated after creating the SSH key

Comment: Anyway, the passphrase is entered when prompted to access the *secret key*. The *public key* (“SHA”?) is added to github. Don’t share the secret key or passphrase.

Comment: @user2864740 okay, understood. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTTPS URL, you need to use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) with scope `repo` as a password.
And you need to cache it using a credential helper, like [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) (cross platform). Once that helper is installed:

```
git config credential.helper manager
```

Should you switch to an SSH URL (`git@github.com:<me>/<myRepo>`), you need, if you have protected your private SSH key with a passphrase, to auto-launch ssh-agent when you start a new session. See "[Working with SSH key passphrases](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases)".